# Passing objects or primitive IDs to other classes?

Tags: design-patterns

I am building an app where the user is able to create new objects (for instance, `articles`). Each article has a primitive unique ID and the all of those articles are stored in a SQL database as well as locally in a dataset (for instance, `articleHolder` list).

To keep data fresh I am rebuilding the whole local `acricleHolder` from SQL DB every now and then. This results in `article` objects having new references. Due to that I have to be very careful as I might get a memory leak or duplicated items.

For example, if I pass an `article` object in another class (for instance, `FavoriteArticleView` and afterwards the `articleHolder` dataset gets rebuilt with all `article` objects having new reference ids, the articles in `FavoriteArticleView` and `articleHolder` might be the same but the references are different so they are treated as different.

So as far as I see I have two solutions:

- Pass a primitive ID to the new classes (`FavoriteArticleView`) and then lookup the `article` object in the `articleHolder` dataset. This lookup potentially creates overhead depending on the `articleHolder` size and type.
- Pass the object but instead of completely rebuilding the `articleHolder` dataset, update the contents of the objects. This would result in maintaining the reference of the object but requires more work.

Are there any better solutions?

Comment: I'm a bit confused: Are you saying that the `ArticleHolder` is a cache? If this is the case, you can use a [read-through cache](http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/articles/readthru-writethru-writebehind.html), where the elements in the cache expire after a certain amount of time. In this way, you only load something from the DB if the item was expired from the cache. And don't implement the cache yourself! There are plenty of open source libraries that will do this for you. (by the way, what I mentioned here has nothing to do with Dependency Injection)

Comment: Agree with @Augusto 's suggestion. In future, you may have to deploy your app on a cluster. In that case, an in-memory article holder per node, wont be a good idea.